# how to make icons of bottom navigation bar transparent?

Tags: android, transparent, android-bottomnav

I am working on an android app where I have to take icons of bottom navigation bar transparent without any tint layer. How can I do that?

I have tried @android:itemIconTint="@color/tranparent" But it is not working
Here is my code :
activity_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_round_bg"
            app:elevation="10dp"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
            app:itemIconSize="30dp"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

bottom_nav_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_trimester"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_trimester_chart"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:title="@string/trimester_chart"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tools"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:title="@string/tools"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dairy"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar_and_diary_logo"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:title="@string/calendar_and_diary"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_blogs"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_blogs"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:title="@string/blogs"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: You need to add more info, for example, is the bottom nav bar of the app you are creating, or the bottom nav buttons of the android system? What have you tried except android:itemIconTint? Give more code to work with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MOTIVECODEX  check details. I have include my code also... If you need more information. then also tell me.